# OroPlatform: how to implement FileType

Tags: symfony, orocommerce

I need to add a FileType field to the Customer User Entity.

I tried to add it directly in backoffice and it's fine : [backoffice screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kM0Dx.png)

But now, I would like to implement it. Is there any documentations to achieve this? Should I use the OroAttachmentBundle?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. OroAttachmentBundle provides files management features.

Follow the documentation to create a field from the code: https://doc.oroinc.com/bundles/platform/AttachmentBundle/attachment-bundle-config/#attachment-bundle-migration-extension.